# grunt-ng-constant targets not consistently working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs

I am running into a weird issue with `grunt-ng-constant` where only 2 out of 3 of the targets work.

My configuration looks like the following:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  ngconstant: {
    options: {
      space: '  ',
      wrap: '"use strict";\n\n {%= __ngModule %}',
      name: 'config'
    },
    // Environment targets
    development: {
      options: {
        dest: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/config.js',
      },
      constants: {
        ENV: {
          name: 'development',
          apiEndpoint: 'http://your-development.api.endpoint:3000'
        }
      }
    },
    staging: {
      options: {
        dest: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/config.js',
      },
      constants: {
        ENV: {
          name: 'staging',
          apiEndpoint: 'http://your-staging.api.endpoint:3000'
        }
      }
    },
    production: {
      options: {
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/config.js',
      },
      constants: {
        ENV: {
          name: 'production',
          apiEndpoint: 'http://api.livesite.com'
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

and I have the following tasks being registered

```
 grunt.registerTask('development', [
    'ngconstant:development'
 ]);

 grunt.registerTask('staging', [
    'ngconstant:staging'
 ]);

 grunt.registerTask('production', [
   'ngconstant:production'
 ]);
```

If I run the two following commands, everything works fine and the `config.js` file is generated and looks great.

```
grunt development
grunt staging
```

but running `grunt production` doesn't generate the `config.js` file. I can't seem to figure out why this is happening.

Comment: Does the `grunt production` command return errors? Which version of each library are you using? I was able to successfully generate all three doing a quick test based on the code you supplied. Can you run `grunt production --verbose` and share the output?

Answer (score 1):

I both developmend and staging tasks you are generating `config.js` file in a path beginning with `<%= yeoman.app %>`, but in production you are using one that starts with `<%= yeoman.dist %>`.

I would check if the second path (or `yeoman.dist`) exists.